# Convert translational stiffness to rotational stiffness of a screw

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bolting, stiffness

I have the formula for the translational stiffness which is : 
[image]

However, what I would like to find is the rotational stiffness. Is there any formulas to convert from one to an other knowing the pitch of the screw and the diameter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translational stiffness is written as
$$ k_l = \frac{A\,E}{\ell},$$ 
where the stiffness $k_l$ is in $\left[\frac{N}{m}\right]$, the area $A$ is in $\left[m^2\right]$, the young's modulus is in $\left[\frac{N}{m^2}\right]$ and the length $\ell$ is in $\left[m\right]$.

$$\,$$

The rotational stiffness is written as
$$ k_r = \frac{G\,J}{\ell},$$
where the stiffness $k_r$ is in $\left[\frac{Nm}{rad}\right]$, the second moment of area (or torsion constant) $J$ is in $\left[m^4\right]$, the rigidity modulus is in $\left[\frac{N}{m^2}\right]$ and the length $\ell$ is in $\left[m\right]$.

$$\,$$

Assuming linear elasticity the following relation between the rigidity modulus and the young modulus holds
$$ G = \frac{E}{2(1+v)},$$
where $v$ is the poison ratio.

$$\,$$

The second moment of area (or torsion constant) for a circle is
$$ \iint\limits_{R} r^2\,dA =
   \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r r^2\left(r\,dr\,d\theta\right) = 
   \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r r^3\,dr\,d\theta =
   \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{r^4}{4}\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}r^4 =
   \frac{A\,r^2}{2}.
$$

$$\,$$

Hence the rotational stiffness of a cylinder can be rewritten as function of $k_l$
$$ k_r = \frac{\frac{E}{2(1+v)} \frac{A\,r^2}{2}}{\ell} =
   \frac{A\,E}{\ell} \frac{r^2}{4(1+v)} =
   k_l \, \frac{r^2}{4(1+v)}
$$

This equation does not hold for any other shape!

When looking at a screw, there is a thread at the outside which has a significant effect on the rotational stiffness.

For example, leaving half the diameter open in the cylinder, the stiffness will only decrease $0.0625\%$ which is insignificant. Increasing the outer radius will increase the stiffness significant.

Comment: The formula is how to calculate the rotational stiffness from the screw parameters. But what I'm trying to do is convert the translational stiffness into rotational stiffness. Without knowing G or J.

Comment: I improved my answer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: There is not any correlation between axial stiffness in a prismatic section and torque or rotational stiffness. J which is mass moment of inertia of the section is dependent on the cross section of the piece and weather it is hollow or solid!

Comment: @kamran there is a correlation between them since I assumed linear elasticity and that the cylinder is solid.

Comment: What if the bar is shaped like an "H" or anything other than a cylinder? The OP has not restricted the cross-section to cylinder.

Comment: @kamran OP did not ask for a general solution. He asked for a screw (last sentence).

Comment: @kamran I updated the answer so it's clear.

Comment: You are right. Then one would have to deal with the thread of the screw which is not insignificant because its located farthest from the neutral axis. I would estimate it has to be considered as a small wedge stressed in compound tension and to a second degree to bending/twisting out of its axis of symmetry. And if the thread pitch is wide it will twist the screw's axis into a spiral.

Comment: @kamran, I think you can neglect the thread when area of the thread is small with respect to the cylinder shape. If you do not neglect the thread, you need to use tensor calculus to solve this problem. Looking at the question I don't think OP can handle that.

Comment: Yes, right. Just to contrast the effect of thread in axial loading to torque, in axial loading its effect is truly insignificant but in rotational loading its effect is substantial. -i.e. if we carve out the center half of cylinder the rotational stiffness is reduced by only 0.0675% of solid core.

Comment: @kamran, you're right but it is reduced with 0,0625% instead of 0,0675%.